# How to install Mupen64plus on ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10

Can't seem to find a way to run Mupen64plus on ubuntu 13.10. Kind of new to ubuntu, but i've had previous experience. i can find it in the store but it's not in my installed applications. Please help. appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Go into the "Ubuntu Software Center" and search for "Mupen64Plus" and look for "Plugin-based Nintendo 64 emulator (transitional dummy package)" and click "Install" Wait for it to install and then click CTRL + ALT + T and run the following into your terminal 'Mupen64plus' without the quotes... Hope this works! Good luck! (By the way... Mupen64Plus doesn't have a front end so you'll always have to run it in a terminal and give it a path to your rom)